# What are init best practices in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift2

If I create a swift class,

```
class Banana {
    init(){
    }
}
```

I can initialize a Banana object with

```
myBanana = Banana.init()
```

But I'm curious, would it be preferable to initialize a Banana object with with simply

```
myBanana = Banana()
```

? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by "**HOW** would I initialize..."? Since `Banana()` is calling the `init`.

Comment: @AlejandroIván hit the nail on the head. My question was misphrased. I'm mentally migrating from C++ to Swift, and I'm still a bit fuzzy on some best practices. I had read the passage IanAuld posted more than once, but for some reason, seeing it in the context here with everyone's comments, it clicked. Apologies and thanks.

Comment: So do you want to rephrase your question or is it answered?

Comment: Thanks, @Qbyte--I rephrased it and marked it answered. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html):

> Initializers
>
> Initializers are called to create a new instance of a particular type.
>   In its simplest form, an initializer is like an instance method with
>   no parameters, written using the init keyword:
>
> ```
> init() {
>     // perform some initialization here
> }
> ```
>
> The example below defines a new structure called Fahrenheit to store
>   temperatures expressed in the Fahrenheit scale. The Fahrenheit
>   structure has one stored property, temperature, which is of type
>   Double:
>
> ```
> struct Fahrenheit {
>     var temperature: Double
>     init() {
>         temperature = 32.0
>     }
> }
> var f = Fahrenheit()
> print("The default temperature is \(f.temperature)° Fahrenheit")
> // prints "The default temperature is 32.0° Fahrenheit"
> ```

Comment: I'm wondering if his question would be better written as **what's the "correct" way of calling an initializer?** comparing `Class.init()` to simply using `Class()` and why? Looks like that to me.

Comment: please, see @AlejandroIván note. Even though the citation is from apple docs, you can see, that init() is NOT like any instance method. Class.init() looks more like class method, but it is NOT true as well. Initialization is little bit more complex process and it is better don't think about constructor Class() and / or Class.init() as about instance, class or type methods.